# Error with Extracting PDF metadata using Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, apache-tika

I am using Solr 3.3 and I am trying to extract and index meta data from PDF files. I am using the DataImportHandler with the TikaEntityProcessor to add the documents. Here is are the fields as defined in my schema.xml file:

```
<field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <field name="description" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <field name="date_published" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <field name="link" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false"/>
   <field name="imgName" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false"/>
   <dynamicField name="attr_*" type="textgen" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

So I suppose the meta data information should be indexed and stored in fields prefixed as "attr_".

Here is how my data config file looks. It takes a source directory path from a database, passes it to a FileListEntityProcessor which will pass each of the pdf files found in the directory to the TikaEntityProcessor to extract and index the content.

```
<entity onError="skip" name="fileSourcePaths" rootEntity="false" dataSource="dbSource" fileName=".*pdf" query="select path from file_sources">
      <entity name="fileSource" processor="FileListEntityProcessor" transformer="ThumbnailTransformer" baseDir="${fileSourcePaths.path}" recursive="true" rootEntity="false">
        <field name="link" column="fileAbsolutePath" thumbnail="true"/>
        <field name="imgName" column="imgName"/>
        <entity rootEntity="true" onError="abort" name="file" processor="TikaEntityProcessor" url="${fileSource.fileAbsolutePath}" dataSource="fileSource" format="text">
          <field column="resourceName" name="title" meta="true"/>
          <field column="Creation-Date" name="date_published" meta="true"/>
          <field column="text" name="description"/>
        </entity>
      </entity>
```

It extracts the description and Creation-date just fine but it doesn't seem like it is extracting resourceName and so  there is no title field for the documents when I query the index . This is weird because both Creation-date and resourceName are meta data. Also, none of the other possible meta data was being stored under the attr_ fields. I came across some threads which said there are know problems with using Tika 0.8 so I downloaded Tika 0.9 and replaced it over 0.8. I also downloaded and replaced pdfbox, jempbox and fontbox from 1.3 to 1.4.

I tested one of the pdf's separately with just Tika to see what meta data is stored with the file. This is what I found:

```
Content-Length: 546459 
Content-Type: application/pdf 
Creation-Date: 2010-06-09T12:11:12Z 
Last-Modified: 2010-06-09T14:53:38Z 
created: Wed Jun 09 08:11:12 EDT 2010 
creator: XSL Formatter V4.3 MR9a (4,3,2009,1022) for Windows 
producer: Antenna House PDF Output Library 2.6.0 (Windows) 
resourceName: Argentina.pdf 
trapped: False 
xmpTPg:NPages: 2
```

As you can see, it does have a resourceName meta data. I tried indexing again but I got the same result. Creation-date extracts and indexes just fine but not resourceName. Also the rest of the attributes are not being indexed under the attr_ fields.

Whats going wrong?